# jQuery UI - Unable to Trigger Spinstop on Spinner

Tags: jquery-ui, triggers, spinner

I'm having trouble triggering the `"spinstop"` event I have set for a jQuery UI spinner

I have created a number of spinner elements that update the sum total text box at the bottom on a `stop:` event. I also have a "Reset" button that will reset all the values back to 0.

Clicking on the "Reset" button will reset the values in the elements, but will not trigger the `stop:` event to reset the values.

I have tried changing the spinner event to `spin:` or `change:` with the same result (actually, `change:` doesn't have the behaviour I wanted).

Below is an example code.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="number" /><br />
<input type="text" class="number" /><br />
<input type="text" class="number" /><br />
<input type="text" class="number" /><br />
<input type="text" id="total" /><br />
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.sum = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    this.each(function () {
        sum += 1 * ($(this).val());
    });
    return sum;
};

$(".number").spinner({
    stop: function () {
        $("#total").val($(".number").sum());
    }
}).val(0);

$("#total").val($(".number").sum());

$("#reset").click(function () {
    $(".number").val(0).trigger("spinstop");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RedXian/wvg1f7t7/)